# How to add a Link that is visible only to admins on a page?

Tags: drupal

I'd like some easy solution to adding a URL link visible only to admins on a page. There are links for "add media" when you're in admin mode on galleries, how could that be achieved for a custom link?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a block and configure the visibility settings.

Go to structure -> Blocks -> Add Block

and fill the Block Body with your links.

Now scroll down to the visibility settings, choose roles and check the administrator role.